# Regex multiple line match recursively in subfolders (one liner)

Tags: regex, linux, perl, sed, awk

I currently use the following Perl one liner to match multiple lines in files recursively among subfolders. It works except that it forces you to use a **`.`** to match a **`\n`**. But I am in need to use **`\n`** because the **`.`** will also match any char.

Is there any way to do this with a Perl one liner ? How about one liners with other Linux programs ?

```
perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/FIND/REPLACE/smg' $(find "/PATH-TO-DIRECTORY" -name "*.html" -type f)
```

**EDIT :**

Regex: **\thello world!....**

Regex: **\thello world!\n\n\n\n**

Test example:

```
    hello world!


    hello world!
    foo
```

Comment: I'm not following you. Why are you forced to use a `.` to match a newline?

Comment: Your edit hasn't made your problem clearer to me. The second regex (`\thelloworld\n\n\n\n`) matches just fine.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Actually, you're right. It does work using \n. WTF ? I must have used a different one-liner. Feel free to delete this post.

Comment: No worries :) - I think you can delete your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tree of directories and files that would result in the situation below:

```
$ cat $(find a -type f)
EFabcd
EFbacA
QuuxQuuxr
Foobar
abcd
```

Then, using sed I think I got a solution for what you are looking for:

```
$ sed -n 'H;${x;s/d\nEF/FOO/;p;}' $(find a -type f)
```

How does it work? First, we suppress the output of sed with `-n`. Then comes the command. For each line, we append a newline and the content of the line to the hold space:

```
H
```

At the end of the file, it bring the content of the hold space to the pattern space (where the replacement can be made):

```
x
```

After this, we have all the content of all the files treated as a sole line. Now we can replace a pattern which includes a new line as well, such as:

```
s/d\nEF/FOO/
```

Once the replacement applied, we print the result:

```
p
```

The result:

```
$ sed -n 'H;${x;s/d\nEF/FOO/g;p;}' $(find a -type f)

EFabcFOObacA
QuuxQuuxr
Foobar
abcd
```

(Note that there is an empty line at the beginning of the result. It is easy to repair as well, I believe.)

Is something like this what are you looking for?

Comment: This one liner does not replace strings in files; it outputs to stdin. Yes, the output starts with an empty line.